# Crear Nodo en Firebase Database a partir de otro nodo existente

Tags: android-studio, firebase, hashmap

Quiero pasar los datos del Nodo Preorden a un nuevo llamado Listado_Facturas_Producto, pero al momento de pasar los datos el problema es que solo toma el hijo final y no todos los que se encuentran como se muestra en las siguientes imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código para la lectura del nodo Preorden es el siguiente:

```
ProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Preorden").child(IdMesero).child("Caja");
 public void CargarPlatos()
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Platos> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Platos>()
                        .setQuery(ProductRef.child(IdMesa_1), Platos.class)
                        .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Platos, Factura_View_Holder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Platos, Factura_View_Holder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Factura_View_Holder holder, int position, @NonNull final Platos model)
                    {
                        DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

                        holder.txtNombre_Plato.setText(model.getPlato());
                        holder.txtCantidad_Plato.setText(model.getCantidad());
                        holder.txtPrecio_Plato.setText(model.getPrecio());
                        holder.txtPrecio_Total.setText(form.format(model.getPrecio_Total()));
```

Y el codigo para pasar al nodo Listado_Factura_Productos es el siguiente

```
final String saveCurrentTime_3, Cabecera_listado_productos;
String cedula_cliente_productos = Cedula_Cliente.getText().toString().trim();

Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
saveCurrentTime_3 = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());

Cabecera_listado_productos = "( " + saveCurrentTime_3 +" )"+ "( " + cedula_cliente_productos + " )";

final DatabaseReference facturas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Listado_Factura_Productos");

HashMap<String, Object> cartMap_productos = new HashMap<>();

cartMap_productos.put("Plato",holder.txtNombre_Plato.getText().toString());
cartMap_productos.put("Precio", holder.txtPrecio_Plato.getText().toString());
cartMap_productos.put("Cantidad", holder.txtCantidad_Plato.getText().toString());
cartMap_productos.put("Precio_Total", holder.txtPrecio_Total.getText().toString());

facturas.child(Cabecera_listado_productos).child("Pedidos")
        .child(holder.txtNombre_Plato.getText().toString()).updateChildren(cartMap_productos);
```